# Swift - Extra argument 'error' in call / nil / call can throw

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to use the core data with swift.
And I got

Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '()'  and
Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

on "context.save(nil)"

and

Extra argument 'error' in call
on "var result: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil)"

what happened?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class vcMain: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnSave(){
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


        var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newUser.setValue("Test Username", forKey: "username")
        newUser.setValue("Test Password", forKey: "password")

        print(newUser)
        print("SAVED")
        context.save(nil)

    }

    @IBAction func btnLoad(){
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        var result: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil)

// - (nullable NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error;



    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: You're using Swift 1 in Xcode 7. But Xcode 7 comes with Swift 2. Convert the code to Swift 2. For your specific case search SO there's already examples.

Answer (score 3):

The executeFetchRequest method of NSManagedObjectContext is a throwing function, so you'll have to wrap it in a do catch statement and handle any error it may throw.

```
var users: [Users]

do {
  users = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Users]
} catch {
  // handle error
}
```

You can also use the try? keyword if you which to handle all errors in the same way:

```
if let users = try? context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Users] {

} else {
  // handle error
}
```

Read: [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:)
and [Swift error handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)